# Android error exception: E/AndroidRuntime(15779): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I keep getting this error message when i run my game:

```
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6373)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:878)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:361)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1483)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:361)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:17566)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6914)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4096)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3954)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3929)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at com.gamerscave.corpboss.Game.Overview_Viewupdate(Game.java:305)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at com.gamerscave.corpboss.Game.tick(Game.java:174)
01-21 16:14:00.911: E/AndroidRuntime(15779):    at com.gamerscave.corpboss.game.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:27)
```

this error code is caused by:

```
    public void Overview_Viewupdate(){
    tv1.setText("Balance: " + Maths.coustomFormat(DEFAULT_BIG_NUMBER_PATTERN, bal));
    tv2.setText("Income: " + Maths.coustomFormat(DEFAULT_BIG_NUMBER_PATTERN, inc));
    tv3.setText("Nett worth: " + Maths.coustomFormat(DEFAULT_BIG_NUMBER_PATTERN, NettWorth));
    tv4.setText("Shares: " + sharePercent + "%");
    tv5.setText("Share value: " + ShareVal);
    tv6.setText("Date: " + Date);
}
```

and it is called at:

```
    public void tick(){
    player.tick();

    long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;

    if(elapsed>1000)
    {
        nextDay(day, year, month);
        System.out.println("New day: " + day);
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    if(view1){
        Overview_Viewupdate();
    }

}
```

for some reason it isnt triggered on the launch. the launch change is called in the init method. the init method is called from the GameThread-class' run method. So how do I avoid this error and still have a game thread that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error above happens because Android doesn’t want other threads, such as your timer, messing with its GUI. So, what you need to do is politely ask Android to make the update for you.

```
public void tick(){
  player.tick();

  long elapsed = (System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;

  if(elapsed>1000)
  {
    nextDay(day, year, month);
    System.out.println("New day: " + day);
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
  }

  if(view1){
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){  
           Overview_Viewupdate(); 
      }   
  });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are updating UI elements on a non-UI thread. There's a couple of ways around this. In your case, I believe the best way is to use a [RunOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) statement, as follows (Note, this has to be done on an Activity):

RuOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
void run() {
    Overview_Viewupdate();
}
});
Your problem is that you are updating UI elements on a non-UI thread. There's a couple of ways around this. In your case, I believe the best way is to use a [RunOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) statement, as follows (Note, this has to be done on an Activity):

```
RuOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
void run() {
    Overview_Viewupdate();
}
});
```

This code would replace your current calling of `Overview_ViewUpdate`. Alternatively, you could consider an [AysncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), where your OnPostExecute runs `Overview_ViewUpdate()` and your `doInBackground()` does the operations that must be run in the background.

Also, make sure your UI elements are created on the UI thread. This is usually done in `OnCreate` or `OnStart`. `AddContentView(...)` or `SetContentView(...)` counts as such.